# Image around the progress bar circle issue

Tags: css, progress-bar, bootstrap-4

Im added progress bar circle, I need to add image around the progress bar, but I cant do it correctly. I've added the background for the image, but its not good solution because I need to create for the list, maybe 40 circles, 
how to add correctly image around the progress bar?

I'm using this http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Dynamic-Circular-Progress-Bar-with-jQuery-CSS3.html

This is example (im try to make like this)

[image]

I've this code:

```
.progress-bar div span {
  position: absolute;
  color:transparent;
  line-height: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
  left: 12.5px;
  top: 12.5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
 background:url(user.png)no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with jquery.

First, create a variable that contains an array, you can name it however you want.

```
var images = [
'https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg',
'https://www.nycgo.com/images/uploads/homepage/Empire-State-Building-Observatory-Tom-Perry-2618.jpg',
'https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg'
```

Then you say that for each `.progress-bar div span`, add a css element`background-image` with the url to your pictures, that you take from the `images` variable.

```
var i=0
$('.progress-bar div span').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url('+images[i]+')');
    i = (i + 1) % images.length;
});
```

Try it and let me know if it helped you!.

**EDIT**

The example below will give you a general idea on how it works.

```js
var images = [
  'https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg',
  'https://www.nycgo.com/images/uploads/homepage/Empire-State-Building-Observatory-Tom-Perry-2618.jpg',
  'https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg'
];

var i = 0;
$('.progress-bar div span').each(function() {
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i] + ')');
  i = (i + 1) % images.length;
})
```

```css
.progress-bar div span {
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div>
      <span> Testing </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div>
      <span> Testing </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div>
      <span> Testing </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is another example that has circles:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXLozZ

Comment: Sir what do you mean, its is a not my  question for correct answer

Comment: You want to add different images to each one of the circles, right? Well, the code let's you put paths to each one of the images in a variable, then it adds those images as a background to each one of your circles.

Comment: Can you tell me why you downvoted this so I can modify the code?. I tested this on my local and it works as intented, all you need to do is implement it into your code and every circle will have a different background.

Comment: Sir, i don't know im not put downvote your answer,don't be misunderstand

Comment: My bad, so can you tell me what is wrong with the code? so I am able to help you.

Comment: i think someone put the downvoted you are make rectangle , its not progress circle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153343/discussion-between-ovidiu-unguru-and-core114).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution 
Im used `jquery-circle-progress`

https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress

im used this   `<span class="schoolclass-pro-bar-img"></span>` and im put the image between `<span>` tag

```
 <div ID="circle1">
<span class="schoolclass-pro-bar-img"></span>
</div>
```